# How to use Handlebars.js and Smarty both?

Tags: smarty, handlebars.js

I am using Smarty for server-side templating and I want to use Handlebars.js for client-side templating but Smarty couse error because Handlebars use curly brackets same as Smarty.
I can write Handlebars template in literal tags of Smarty but I cant use Smarty in Handlebars  template this time.

For example:
I write a smarty block function for cleanurl. I dont want to write a cleanurl function for javascript.So I want to use Smarty and Handlebars.js both.

```
<div class="model-item" id="model-{{id}}">
    <a href="{$mainurl}{cu}?com=model&act=view&id={{id}}{/cu}"> {{name}} </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use literal tags...much better than escaping each curly brace.

```
{literal}
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{any_var}}
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: literal tags are good but when I use smarty and mustache vars both, code doing very complex and confusing. I decided to use underscore micro template and I am  glad :)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.escaping.tpl

this section of the documentation discussing escaping.  I think the "{ldelim},{rdelim}" may be what you are looking for...although it makes the code a bit less readable...

Comment: I can use {ldelim} and {rdelim} but I must write the the all of the handlebars's brackets as {ldelim},{rdelim}.I think this may cause confusing also I think this delay development process.I cant change delimeters of Smarty because I using it in most places.I did not use handlebars anywhere.I can change delimeters of handlebars.Is this a good idea ? and this is possible?

Comment: perhaps write a custom function to output the brackets... (in Smarty)

Comment: I found [set delimeter tags](http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html) at mustache documentation.This exactly what am I looking.On handebars's site 
__"Mustache templates are compatible with Handlebars, so you can take a Mustache template, import it into Handlebars, and start taking advantage of the extra Handlebars features."__.Is there the feature in Handlebars?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this is now a supported smarty feature.
(I stumbled across your question when I was looking for the same, so I wanted to answer it incase anyone else has the same issue)

if you add this:

`$smarty->setLiterals(array('{{{','}}}','{{','}}'));`

Smarty will now ignore all double and triple delims for mustache and handlebars.
Note:
Before enabling one must check their existing smarty templates for any legit smarty use of {{ or {{{ and rework their code as after setting, these are now literals and they will not longer function as smarty statements.

https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/508#issuecomment-437640751

this is as of version 3.1.32